# Updating "How to Root" Format Question

Tags: support, editing, community-wiki, suggested-edits

I was going to update the wiki question [How do I root my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device) to include the Samsung Galaxy S4, but I wanted to make sure the update I was going to add was following the proper formatting, linking, etc. for the answer.

I was going to add the Galaxy S4 and link to this xda post:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2290798

However it seems to be limited to Verizon and doesn't work on the most recent Build release.

So then I found the following infromation for the the root method of the most recent Build:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2359090

So I was going to add the Galaxy S4 as follows:

- [Galaxy S4 SCH-I545 (Verizon Build VRUAMDK)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2290798)
- [Galaxy S4 SCH-I545 (Verizon Build VRUAME7) (Currently Not Available, Bounty Open)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2359090)

I wanted to make sure if this was a proper way of adding the S4's root to the list? Should I not include the VRUAME7 Build link since it is not really a root method? Should I not include the VRUAMDK Build since it won't work for most people (if they didn't update it will work at least)?

**DISCLAIMER:** I am in NO way a part of the bounty or currently working on it (I'm not that smart :)). There is no gain in this for me except wanting my S4 rooted and contributing to Android.SE & StackExchange (I found SE first and like you guys & gals more).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All entries in that post should link to questions on our site now.  If you see any that don't, please remove them :)

Feel free to *post* a question asking how to root your S4, assuming there is not such a question already.  When that question is answered, either by yourself after you figure out the process or by someone else, then it should be added to the big list.

Comment: How about a post that links to an answer on android.se, but then that answer links to xda? And I think there may have been the general "root my S4" question, but not for my more specific needs with the build version so that would be an acceptable question/not a duplicate?

Comment: @TronicZomB Link-only answers are discouraged.  References to sources are encouraged :).  Close variants should all be part of one question, IMO

Comment: Ok, I hadn't read the post fully that I mentioned in the last comment, its for the Galaxy S3 and it links to android.se and references xda. I will work on a post of similar structure in time since there doesn't seem to be question on rooting the S4 just yet. Thanks for your help!